# How to use CARTO map visualization in Odyssey.js sandbox

Tags: carto, web-mapping, carto-js, odyssey-js, carto-vl

I have a story map in Odyssey's sandbox GUI. I want to use a visualization I have in CARTO as a base map for this map. How can I find my viz key? All the documentation seems to refer to an option that is no longer available. The documentation says to find it in the share options and click on CARTO.js, which is no longer an option inside CARTO builder.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the new version of Builder visualizations are not compatible with Odyssey.js. But [as explained in this CARTO HELP article](https://carto.com/help/building-maps/story-maps/), you can use CARTO.js (and CARTO VL!) in combination with other storytelling libraries to create your own storymap.